# Update option total pages with ajax in Jquery Plugin wpaginate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with wpaginate Jquery Plugin: https://github.com/websanova/wPaginate . It has total attribute which is total number of records. But I don't know how to make it works properly.

Javascript:

```
$.get(rootUrl + "js/my_cursostotal.php", {}, function(data){ 
$('#wPCursos').wPaginate({
    theme: 'lightblue',
    total: data,
    limit: 3,
    url: function(i) {
        $('#wPCursos').wPaginate('total', data);
        loadCursos('action=ajax&page='+ (i+1) );
        },
        ajax: true
    });
});

function loadCursos(str) {
    //$("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
    $('#cursosTabla').load('index.php?'+str,function() {
        //$("#loader").fadeOut('slow');
    });
    console.log("%s", str);
}
```

my_cursostotal.php

```
$cursos_total = $cursos_tabla->total();
echo $cursos_total;
```

When I delete or add elements elements of the table $cursos_total change, but the total pages are not updated until I click 2 page items.

I have used console.log('%s' data) and I get the correct elements in it, but the wpaginate item doesn't take it until I click two times in pages, then appears the new page or drop a page.

What can I do? It's important for me.

I think that I have to modify the Jquery Plugin, but I have no idea. I have tried, but it's very complicated for me.

I want only how to make to reset the settings of jQuery plugin wpaginate to display properly the number of pages.

You have a demo of the plugin here: http://wpaginate.websanova.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have find some help and I've solved it:

```
$.get(rootUrl + "js/my_cursostotal.php", {}, function(data){ 
$('#wPCursos').wPaginate({
    theme: 'lightblue',
    total: data,
    limit: 3,
    url: function(i) {
        $.get(rootUrl + "js/my_cursostotal.php", {}, function(data){ 
            $('#wPCursos').wPaginate('total', data);
            $('#wPCursos').data('_wPaginate').generateLinks();
        });
        loadCursos('tabla=cursos&action=ajax&page='+ (i+1) );
    },
    ajax: true
});
});
```

"$('#wPCursos').data('_wPaginate').generateLinks();" makes the trick.